# Select Dropdowns intermittently not setting value

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have several dropdown selects on a page, which are all populated from AJAX calls. Each one of these will have a default option set (this is an "Edit" page for an end-user), however I've noticed random dropdowns will intermittently not have their value set.
It happens to different dropdowns and for different recordsets and I don't know why or how to code the page to ensure all have been correctly set before rendering the view?
Code examples below...

The dropdowns:

```
    <div class="form-group row" id="d2">
        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label required">Business Owner</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <select class="form-control" id="cmb1">
                <option value="" selected>-Select-</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The AJAX call to populate:

```
function FillDD1() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("/NewMeasure1")/',
                type: "GET",
                success: function (qx) {
                    var trHTML = '';
                    $.each(qx, function (i, item) {
                        trHTML += '<option value="' + item.people_PK + '">' + item.name + '</option>';
                    });
                    $('#cmb1').append(trHTML);
                },
                error: function () {
                    var trHTML = '';
                    trHTML = 'Error fetching data';
                    $('#cmb1').append(trHTML);
                }
            })
        };
```

The code that sets the value:

```
function FetchMeasureInfo() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("/FetchMeasureInfo")/',
                type: "GET",
                data: {
                    measurekey: getSessionInfo
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var count = Object.keys(data).length;
                    console.log(count);
                    if (count == 0) {
                        msg = "AJAX Error. Server responded but with an incomplete recordset for Measure PK " + getSessionInfo
                        AddErrorLog();
                        $('#nodata').fadeIn('slow');
                        $('#form').hide();
                    }

                    $("#cmb1").val(data[0].BusinessOwnerKey).change();
                    $("#cmb1a").val(data[0].GatekeeperKey).change();
                    $("#cmb2").val(data[0].availabilityKey).change();

                    var troy = $('#cmb4 :selected').val()

                    if (troy == '') {
                        $('#missinginfo').slideDown('slow');
                        msg = "Alert for missing info shown. Saving edits may not work correctly."
                        AddErrorLog();
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    msg = "The database could not be found. Possible network issue."
                    AddErrorLog();
                }
            })
        };
```

And it's called like this:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
            if (sessionStorage.length == 0) {
                $('#form').hide();
                $('#noway').slideDown('slow');
                msg = "Bad Request. User likely loaded page without referrer"
                AddErrorLog();
            }
            else {
                getSessionInfo = sessionStorage.getItem('measure');
                FillDD1();
                FillDD2();
//FillDD3-9 go here
                FetchMeasureInfo();
                $('#form').fadeIn('slow');
                sessionStorage.removeItem('measure');
            }
        });
```

I've removed all the dropdown list code for brevity (they're all the same with the ID being different)

Comment: Why are you not just binding to a model?

Comment: Could do - do you think the issue is down to it not being bound?

Comment: No idea (I don't even know what you data is and if it matches an option value) But to have the client request a page and then degrade performance by having to make further ajax calls to get data that you forgot to send in the first place is crazy (as is not binding to a model)

Comment: Then I'll bind it. I didn't forget. Thanks for your help